Реализация сохранения времени таймера, работающего на фоне, при выключении системы
Не придумал ничего лучше, чем запускать ещё один фоновый поток, в котором время таймера бесконечном цикле постоянно записывается в переменную/файл/базу данных(SQLite) (если конкретно, фиксируется реальное время и время таймера на момент выключения, в момент включения вычисляется (время таймера +(реальное время - реальное время на момент выключения). Может есть более правильное/практичное, готовое решение/инструмент, чтобы это реализовать?
(Система Windows 10)

https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-check-startup-shutdown-history/

Зачем постоянно, достаточно один раз время запуска таймера записать, а всё остальное можно в любой момент посчитать из времени запуска
